# ¿Por qué este css grid no esta alineado y por arriba no hay margen?

Tags: css, css3, css-grid-layout

Estoy haciendo un simple container (`.box`) con 9 containers (`.card`) dentro de él, quiero que queden centrados y que haya un margen entre ellos (grid-gap). Para ello he utilizado `justify-content: center;` sin embargo  no se centra porque arriba no hay margen que hay en izquierda, derecha y abajo.

```css
.box{
  /*
    margin: 20vh auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 650px;
    height: 60vh;
*/
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30%);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 30%);
    grid-gap: 12px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.card{
    border: 2px solid gray;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<div className="box">
            <Card />
            <Card />
            <Card />

            <Card />
            <Card />
            <Card />

            <Card />
            <Card />
            <Card />
        </div>
```

LO que no entiendo es porque horizontalmente la grid si ocupa el 100% y distribuye correctamente la alineación 30% en cada card, como he puesto:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30%);
```

Y sin embargo para alineación vertical no ocupa el 90% y entonces el espacio de abajo no es ocupado y por eso arriba queda "pegado". Sin embargo he puesto lo mismo que en las columnas:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 30%);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo con lo siguiente:

- Crea tu rejilla con ayuda de CSS Grid distribuyendo las 9 cards con un espacio de `1fr` en grupos de 3
- A las cajas o cards que estan dentro del contenedor principal, puedes con ayuda de FlexBox acomodar su contenido de forma vertical y de forma horizontal
- Para lograr que las cards tengan un alto definido, entonces puedes usar `grid-template-rows` con una medida de 150px para cada una de las filas (de las 3 en cuestión)
- Opcionalmente con `nth-child` puedes colocar un color a los elementos pares **even** y así poder identificar los estilos aplicados
- Con fines de lectura visual colocamos al body un color de fondo para identificar si tiene un margen respecto de su contenido interno

Tu código pudiera quedar así:

```html
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      .mesa{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        background-color: pink;
        grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px;
      }
      .elementos{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .elementos:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="mesa">
      <div class="elementos">1</div>
      <div class="elementos">2</div>
      <div class="elementos">3</div>
      <div class="elementos">4</div>
      <div class="elementos">5</div>
      <div class="elementos">6</div>
      <div class="elementos">7</div>
      <div class="elementos">8</div>
      <div class="elementos">9</div>
    </div>
```

> Opcionalmente si necesitas que el elemento que tiene a tu sistema de rejillas posea un margen mas amplio y se separe del mismo, por ejemplo le puedes agregar un `margin` de 20px